# TextColor in Android XML is not working?

Tags: android, xml, colors

I have an android app where I have a textview to represent a question :

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="This is a very very very very very long Question ?"
android:textSize="40dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
android:id="@+id/question"
android:textColor="#d0d0"
android:textColorHint="#d0d0"
android:textColorLink="#d0d0"
android:textColorHighlight="#d0d0"
android:background="#d0d0d0"/>
```

> #d0d0 = Light Green

As you see I've tried all of:

```
android:textColor="#d0d0"
android:textColorHint="#d0d0"
android:textColorLink="#d0d0"
android:textColorHighlight="#d0d0"
```

But the Text view Color still the same (**Gray**) in the phone
*But in Android studio it's working fine*

> I don't want a java solution I want to change the color with XML

Thank you in advance

Comment: May be its due to some bug as i am running in a getting the output with green text and grey background

Comment: Exactly that's what I wanted to say, I've tried many things like `"@android/color/red"` but it shows me a gray color,So do you have any help Sir

Comment: we are in the the same lvl bro (University) .You are getting the error in android studio beta version ??

Comment: @NeelaySrivastava I found the solution look at my answer please

Comment: the string format of color in the resources is #AARRGGBB: A for alpha (ff for highest opacity and 00 for lowest transparency), R for red, G for green and B for the blue component of the color. Eg. #ff000000 is pure black color, while #00000000 is transparent black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors are Represented in 4 bytes: alpha, red, green, blue. Each value range 0 to 255. 
You try to represent the color codes with hexadecimal format #RRGGBB. It should work. It is traditional way in android xml files.

In my mobile your code is working. But may be some mobiles follows only hexadecimal format color representation.

Comment: Thank you so uch Sir, But I've tried many things like `"@android/color/red"` but it shows me a gray color, I think the problem in the android studio, So if you have any idea help me please

Answer (score 1):

Text color is code wrong

## d0d0 - gray color

For light green
Check this link
[green color](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/green-color.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your help Sir, But the problem it's not in the color I've tried many others like `"@android/color/red"` but it shows me a gray color, Please if you have any idea help me

Answer (score 1):

I did somethings and now it's working Fine (*Windows/Mac/Linux)*:

> **1.**  Backup your SDK Folder *(After Installing all the packages)*
>
> **2.** Reinstall Android Studio
>
> **3.** Get back your SDK folder *(override the new one if it exists)*.
>
> **4.** If you have an old project Copy only your XML files and the Java files because maybe there is a problem in the other files

I hope it works for any one have the same problem **^_^**

Comment: Its due to some bug in android studio nothing else no need to reinstall the android studio from next time it will take too much time

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I'm using linux so I can install it by just copying the new files (It' takes only the download time) :) :) :) Thank you SO much Sir

Comment: Please see my comment below your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could have checked by using the Analog colour selector instead of putting the hex code in Android studio. Your code seems fine. There is no reason it won't work. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Kona Suresh, but :

the string format of color in the resources is `#AARRGGBB`: A for alpha (ff for highest opacity and 00 for lowest transparency), R for red, G for green and B for the blue component of the color. Eg. `#ff000000` is pure black color, while `#00000000` is transparent black.