# Android TextView's textColor is wrong only on Physical Device

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, textcolor

For a class, I'm attempting to make a basic greeting card application in Android Studio 2.2, **build #AI-145.3276617**, with **JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b03**.
[image: [PMyAS.png]]

The "card" contain  big image and  few TextViews in a RelativeLayout.

I've attempted to test on a **Nexus 5 API24 emulator** and  **physical Nexus 5** at A**ndroid 6.0.1**.

[image: [PAD.png]]

When I test the app on the emulator, the text color shows properly, but when I run on my physical device, the colors of the text are wrong.

The design view and emulator both seem to be happy with the text:
[image]

But this screen shot from my physical device has different text colors:
[image]

The xml I've included shows me attempting to use hex textColor values directly, but I've also tried to place them as resources with the same result.

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryLight">#BBDEFB</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FFEB3B</color>
    <color name="colorText1">#2196F3</color>
    <color name="colorText2">#1976D2</color>
</resources>
```

My **activity_main.xml** file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    tools:context="com.touchspin.hnspd.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/happy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Happy"
        android:textSize="72sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:textColor="#1976D2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/national"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="National"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/happy"
        android:textColor="#2196F3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sock_puppet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Sock Puppet"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/national"
        android:textColor="#1976D2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/day"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Day!"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/sock_puppet"
        android:textColor="#2196F3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried cleaning the build & restarting Android Studio, resource colors & hard coded hex.  I'd be grateful for any pointing in the correct direction.

Comment: go to your `Physical device` `Settings > Accessibility` and turn off `High contrast text`.

Comment: @Ironman indeed indeed

Comment: please refer this url It may be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808968/textcolor-in-android-xml-is-not-working/39809922#39809922

Comment: For crying out loud.  How embarrassing.  You should have put this in an answer so that I could have credited you with the solution.  My High contrast text option was turned on and killing that fixed my text colors.  thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `LolliPop` device or `LolliPop` upper device. if the `TextColor` is not display well you have disable the `High contrast Text`. which is by default enable.

So To solve the Problem Go to `Settings > Accessibility` and switch off the `High Contrast Text`. It will solve the problem.

Comment: Years later still a very valid hint! Been searching this "bug" in React Native on a single older device for way too long, tried everything, from debugger to a native Java project. It was just a single accessibility option easily missed. Thanks @Ironman!

Comment: Any other solution except disabling High-contrast text?